# Is the Representation Matrix of Every Quantum Channel Diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, diagonalization, quantum-information

Given a [quantum map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_channel#Schr%C3%B6dinger_picture) with input and output states of equal (finite) dimension---that is, a [completely positive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completely_positivmap) trace-preserving linear map $\Phi:\mathbb C^{n\times n}\to\mathbb C^{n\times n}$---is the matrix $\hat\Phi\in\mathbb C^{n^2\times n^2}$ which one obtains from the action of $\Phi$ on a [vectorized state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) $\operatorname{vec}(\rho)$ (i.e. $\hat\Phi$ satisfies $\operatorname{vec}(\Phi(\rho))=\hat\Phi\operatorname{vec}(\rho)$) always diagonalizable?

While this question is trivial if one asks about the [Choi matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/733836/495075) $C(\Phi)$ of $\Phi$ instead -- which is always positive semi-definite because $\Phi$ is completely positive, hence $C(\Phi)$ is even [unitarily diagonalizable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1050580/what-kind-of-a-matrix-has-a-unitary-diagonalizing-matrix) -- this may change if one chooses a different arrangement of the elements of $\Phi$. Note that the matrix $\hat\Phi$ differs from the Choi matrix [as](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4514946/495075) [follows](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/6139/direct-derivation-of-the-kraus-representation-from-the-natural-representation-u/6142#6142):
$$
\langle k\otimes l|\hat\Phi |i\otimes j\rangle=\langle k\otimes i|C(\Phi)|l\otimes j\rangle
$$
One way to see this is directly via
$$
\hat\Phi=\sum_{i,j,k,l=1}^n\big\langle l,\Phi(|i\rangle\langle j|)k\big\rangle\ |k\rangle\langle j|\otimes|l\rangle\langle i|\ .\tag{1}
$$
The motivation here is of course the fact that the spectrum of $\Phi$ and $\hat\Phi$ coincide, whereas the spectrum of $C(\Phi)$ in general differs from that.
As stated before, the question -- most relevant for spectral analysis -- now is:

> If $\Phi$ is a quantum channel, is $\hat\Phi$ always diagonalizable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no, and we give some counter-examples below: two in $2$ and one in $3$ and more dimensions. References for the two-dimensional examples are [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/15/7/073045) and [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2403.19643), and the three-dimensional example also appears in a slightly different form in [these old lecture notes of M. Wolf](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/node?id=1701036&change_language=en) (Example 8.1). However, in my opinion, these examples are rather difficult to find if you're not already familiar with these references---hence why I decided to create this post.
Interestingly, the second paper linked above shows that---while not all channels can be diagonalized---every channel can be approximated by diagonalizable **channels** arbitrarily well.

### 1. The Qubit Case

#### 1a. Example 1

First we will construct some examples based on the [Pauli transfer matrix](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/30045), which is just the representation matrix with respect to the orthonormal basis $\{\frac1{\sqrt2}{\bf1},\frac1{\sqrt2}\sigma_x,\frac1{\sqrt2}\sigma_y,\frac1{\sqrt2}\sigma_z  \}$. The idea here is that the Pauli transfer matrix of a unital (i.e. identity-preserving) qubit channel is [always of the form](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.64.010101)
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0\\0&\Lambda
\end{pmatrix}\tag{1}
$$
for some $\Lambda\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$. Interestingly, the [Fujiwara-Algoet conditions](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevA.59.3290)---which in the unital case are necessary and sufficient conditions on the singular values of $\Lambda$ such that (1) gives rise to a quantum channel---show that for every $\Lambda\in\mathbb R^{3\times 3}$ there exists $c>0$ such that the block-diagonal matrix $1\oplus c\Lambda$ corresponds to a unital channel. This gives rise to a simple machinery to construct non-diagonalizable channels:

> Starting from your favorite non-diagonalizable real $3\times 3$-matrix $\Lambda$, the channel with Pauli transfer matrix $1\oplus c\Lambda$ (for all $c$ "small enough") is not diagonalizable.

To show this construction in action, one of the simplest examples then is the channel with Pauli transfer matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&0&1/2&0\\0&0&0&1/2\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is obviously not diagonalizable. Complete positivity of the corresponding (trace-preserving) linear map
$$
\Phi\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
 \frac{a_{11}+a_{22}}{2} & \frac{1}{4} i (-a_{11}+a_{12}-a_{21}+a_{22}) \\
 \frac{1}{4} i (a_{11}+a_{12}-a_{21}-a_{22}) & \frac{a_{11}+a_{22}}{2} \end{pmatrix}
$$
is due to the fact that its Choi matrix
$$
\frac14\begin{pmatrix}
 2 & -i & 0 & i \\
 i & 2 & i & 0 \\
 0 & -i & 2 & i \\
 -i & 0 & -i & 2
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has eigenvalues $1$, $1/2$ (2-fold), and $0$.
Geometrically, the effect of this three-dimensional Jordan block is that

- first, $\Phi$ maps the Bloch ball to a smaller circle in the $y-z-$plane,
- a second application of $\Phi$ yields (part of) the $z$-axis,
- and applying $\Phi$ a third (and more) times always yields the Bloch vector zero.

This is readily verified by the action of $\Phi$ on any [Bloch vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4099977/495075):
$
\Phi:(x,y,z)^\top\mapsto (y/2,z/2,0)^\top
$.
In contrast, if the eigenvalue $0$ had geometric multiplicity three (while the identity matrix stays the fixed point of $\Phi$) it would not take three, but only *one* application of $\Phi$ to map the whole Bloch ball to the origin.

#### 1b. Example 2 (minimal Kraus rank)

Next, two examples where we focus more on the Kraus rank, and we try to make it as small as possible.
The first one is again a unital channel, now of Kraus rank 2 which has appeared [in the literature before](https://doi.org/10.1088/1367-2630/15/7/073045); its Pauli transfer matrix reads
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&-1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
and it can be written as dephasing followed by the unitary channel generated by
$$
\frac1{\sqrt2}\begin{pmatrix}-1&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
To show that diagonalizability can also fail for non-unital channels consider $\Phi:\mathbb C^{2\times 2}\to\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ defined via
$$
\Phi\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}+\frac23a_{22}&\frac13a_{12}+\frac13a_{22}\\
\frac13a_{21}+\frac13a_{22}&\frac13a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Again, $\Phi$ is obviously trace preserving and $\Phi$ is completely positive because its Choi matrix
$$
C(\Phi)=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&1/3\\
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&2/3&1/3\\
1/3&0&1/3&1/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
has three positive ($\approx 1.177,0.782,0.040$) and one zero eigenvalue.
Even better, the representation matrix of $\Phi$ is already in upper triangular form so we can read off that it has a simple eigenvalue $1$ and a three-fold eigenvalue $1/3$:
$$
\hat\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&2/3\\
0&1/3&0&1/3\\
0&0&1/3&1/3\\
0&0&0&1/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This triangular form, however, already lets one suspect that the geometric multiplicity of the eigenvalue $1/3$ is less than $3$. And indeed, its Jordan normal form reads $\hat\Phi=SJS^{-1}$ with
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3}
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad S=
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & \frac{1}{3} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
Note that this can be used to construct a family of non-diagonalizable channels: simply replace the last column of $\hat\Phi$ by $(2/3,b,b^*,1/3)^T$ for any $b\in\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$. Then $\hat\Phi$ is not diagonalizable, and $\Phi$ is a channel (completely positive) if and only if $|b|\leq\frac{2\sqrt3}9$.
In this limiting case we obtain the in some sense simplest possible example of a non-diagonalizable channel:
$$
\Phi\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}&a_{12}\\a_{21}&a_{22}\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
 a_{11}+\frac{2 a_{22}}{3} & \frac{1}{9} \left(3 a_{12}+2 \sqrt{3} a_{22}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{9} \left(3 a_{21}+2 \sqrt{3} a_{22}\right) & \frac{a_{22}}{3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is a channel with Kraus rank 2 (a choice of Kraus operators is
$$
K_1=\sqrt{\frac{3 +\sqrt3}{18}}\begin{pmatrix} \sqrt3&\sqrt3-1\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad K_2=\sqrt{\frac{3-\sqrt3}{18}}\begin{pmatrix} -\sqrt3&1+\sqrt3\\0&1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
as is readily verified)
but $\hat\Phi$ is not diagonalizable per our previous considerations.

### 2. Higher Dimensions: Classical Channels

Consider the map $\Phi:\mathbb C^{3\times 3}\to\mathbb C^{3\times 3}$ defined via
$$
\Phi\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}&a_{12}&a_{13}\\ 
a_{21}&a_{22}&a_{23}\\ 
a_{31}&a_{32}&a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}:=
\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11}+\frac23a_{22}+\frac13a_{33}&0&0\\ 
0&\frac13a_{22}+\frac13a_{33}&0\\ 
0&0&\frac13a_{33}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so $\Phi$ is even a classical channel, hence the Choi matrix of $\Phi$ is already diagonal.
Using equation (1) it is easy to see that
$$
\hat\Phi=\begin{pmatrix}
1&0&0&0&\frac23&0&0&0&\frac13 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&\frac13&0&0&0&\frac13 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0 \\ 
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\frac13
\end{pmatrix}\simeq
\frac13\begin{pmatrix}
3&2&1\\ 
0&1&1\\ 
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\oplus 0_6\ .
$$
Now the non-trivial part of $\hat\Phi$ (which we will denote by $D_\Phi$ for "diagonal action") is not diagonalizable; indeed the Jordan normal form of $D_\Phi$ reads $SJS^{-1}$ where
$$
J=\begin{pmatrix}
3&0&0\\ 
0&1&1\\ 
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ and }\quad S=\begin{pmatrix}
1&-1&-1\\ 
0&1&0\\ 
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\quad\text{ so }\quad
S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&1&1\\ 
0&1&0\\ 
0&0&1
\end{pmatrix}\,.
$$
For more examples of non-diagonalizable stochastic matrices refer, e.g., to [this math.SE answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/332700/).
Moreover, the structure of this counterexample generalizes to any dimension $n\geq 3$.

---

Addendum: if trace-preservation is dropped, finding a counterexample is a lot easier. Indeed, the—obviously non-diagonalizable—matrix
$$
\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}
$$
is the superoperator corresponding to the map
$$
\Phi(X):=\begin{pmatrix}x_{22}&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
and $\Phi$ is completely positive as $\{|0\rangle\langle 1|\}$ is a set of Kraus operators of $\Phi$. However, $\Phi$ is obviously not trace-preserving.